# Bypassing chrome autopause on videos with sound?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, youtube, tubular

I have a website set-up, where the background is a YouTube video using Tubular.js plugin. There is a problem with chrome browsers, that auto pauses the youtube video if I load it with `mute: false` flag. Chrome is the only offender, as it works with opera, firefox etc. If I change the flag to `mute: true` the video will atuplay fine.

Chrome recently started to block atuplayed videos with sound. Is there an option to bypass this on chrome, or at least modify the tubular.js library/js call so that it will only mute (regardless of settings) on chrome user-agents?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MGEZrO

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to chrome logic it is impossible to autoplay video if it is NOT muted. However they allow to autoplay video if it is **muted** and WILL NOT stop it if **user will unmute it**. By this (user interaction) chrome means just a **single tap OR click by the user** on the website (everywhere, not video components only).

Just make your user to make a single click on your webpage and THEN you can mount/start video with autoplay and sound.

I have the similar situation with my react spa. And I force my user to make a single click before mounting the video. Only this way it starts to play with sound.

I also had the situation where the video MUST have started even without click and the I just addEventListener on whole page to unmute it as soon as possible

```
play(from = null) {
  document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // any click will force my video to unmute
  this.player.muted = false; 
  });
  // rest code for updating state etc
}
```

Unfortunately, triggering click is not working (the video will stop automatically)

Comment: Wow, this is so beautifully evil I think I will stay far away from any implementation of this and instead admire it from a safe distance.

Answer (score 0):

According to their [guidelines about autoplay on chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/audio-video/autoplay) ;

> Unfortunately, Chrome cannot provide any whitelist exceptions to the autoplay policy.

They also explain how to present the content in a less-invasive way (muted video first) and some other tips about the policy.

Comment: I understand why they introduced this, but unfortunately having auto sound is crucial to me. Is there a way to load the video muted first, then unmute it using `<body onload="foo.bar();">` or similar?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. But look in the page and the links under "more information". There is a policy that let you autoplay if you have a "user interaction with the domain". Maybe you can find a compromise, but I don't think you will be able to rollback their policy update.

Comment: According to this blog post https://blog.google/products/chrome/improving-autoplay-chrome/ they admit that they have actually whitelist for about 1000 pages, which is imho very unfair and might by even illegal as it discriminates competition.